# CSS3 : Space between left panel and an iframe div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs. one with fixed left panel and in the 2nd div I have an iframe.

I get slight space between left panel and iframe div. I get proper output in my Laptop. but in another laptop , I get space between left panel and iframe.

How can I fix them?

> Note : I have given width to left panel in Pixel. I don't want to give
>   in percentage. as I want its width to be fixed even If I make it
>   responsive.

```css
.left_panel_div{
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:320px;
  min-height:100%;
  background:gray;
  float:left;
}

.iframe_div{
  float: left;
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
  <div class="left_panel_div"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 padding_left_0">
  <div class="iframe_div">
  <iframe src="http://google.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

[image: space between left panel and iframe div]

In the image , there is a space between 2 div. How can I remove the space to make it look the same for all the laptops , desktops?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe tag default browser style makes it have a grey 2 pixel wide border. You can remove the border. Just can add some CSS style to it:

```
.iframe_div iframe { border: none; }
```

Comment: still i get space between left panel and an iframe div

Comment: if you van share your whole render of HTML / CSS, we can the full picture. This is to much of a guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Why use all the bootstrap classes if you override it anyway. Just strip that out and position everything fixed or absolute.

```css
.left_panel_div{
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:320px;
  min-height:100%;
  background:gray;
}

.iframe_div{
  position: absolute;
  left: 320px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div class="left_panel_div"></div>

  <div class="iframe_div">
    <iframe src="http://google.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```